# SQL NOT IN Query

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, localized, notin

Can anyone help me with this MySQL query?

```
SELECT p.ProductID, 
       p.StoreID, 
       p.DiscountPercentage 
 FROM Products p 
WHERE p.IsSpecial = 1 
  AND p.SpecialDate >= date_sub(now(),interval 15 minute) 
  AND p.DiscountPercentage >= ?DiscountPercentage 
  AND p.ProductID NOT IN (SELECT lf.LiveFeedID 
                            From LiveFeed lf 
                           WHERE p.ProductID = lf.ProductID 
                             AND lf.DateAdded >= date_sub(now(),interval 30 day)) 
  AND p.StoreID NOT IN (SELECT lf.LiveFeedID 
                          From LiveFeed lf 
                         WHERE p.StoreID = lf.StoreID 
                           AND lf.DateAdded >= date_sub(now(),interval 6 hour)) 
ORDER BY p.StoreID, p.DiscountPercentage DESC
```

I'm trying join where the ProductID is not in the livefeed table in the last 30 days and where the storeid is not in the livefeed table in the last 6 hours, but it does not seem to be working.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Updated answer based on your comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At a glance, it would appear that your first subquery should be selecting `ProductID`, not `LiveFeedID` and your second subquery should be selecting `StoreID` not `LiveFeedID`

Comment: ahhh you are correct!  I knew it was something simple that I was missing!  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I'm too late:

```
  SELECT p.ProductID, 
         p.StoreID, 
         p.DiscountPercentage 
    FROM Products p 
   WHERE p.IsSpecial = 1 
     AND p.SpecialDate >= date_sub(now(),interval 15 minute) 
     AND p.DiscountPercentage >= ?DiscountPercentage 
     AND p.ProductID NOT IN (SELECT lf.productid
                               FROM LIVEFEED lf
                              WHERE lf.DateAdded >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)) 
     AND p.storeid NOT IN (SELECT lf.storeid
                             FROM LIVEFEED lf
                            WHERE lf.DateAdded >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 HOUR)) 
ORDER BY p.StoreID, p.DiscountPercentage DESC
```

You were using EXISTS syntax with a correllated subquery...

> I'm trying to get the top discount for each store.

In that case, use:

```
  SELECT p.StoreID, 
         MAX(p.DiscountPercentage)
    FROM Products p 
   WHERE p.IsSpecial = 1 
     AND p.SpecialDate >= date_sub(now(),interval 15 minute) 
     AND p.DiscountPercentage >= ?DiscountPercentage 
     AND p.ProductID NOT IN (SELECT lf.productid
                               FROM LIVEFEED lf
                              WHERE lf.DateAdded >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY)) 
     AND p.storeid NOT IN (SELECT lf.storeid
                             FROM LIVEFEED lf
                            WHERE lf.DateAdded >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 6 HOUR)) 
GROUP BY p.storeid
ORDER BY p.StoreID, p.DiscountPercentage DESC
```

Comment: Thank you!  Is there a simple way to only allow one storeID in the query?

Comment: Only 1? Tack `LIMIT 1` on to the end.  But I'd need to know more about how to determine which specific storeid to return...

Comment: Well, as the query is now, it will return multiple product id's from the same store.  I need a limit of 1 for each storeid within the query.  I'm trying to get the top discount for each store.